# Is it possible in Visual Studio to rename the file being edited without finding it in the solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

Is it possible, via native Visual Studio functionality or ReSharper, to rename the file I'me editing without finding it in the solution explorer?  Or is there another way to do so that is relatively faster than finding it in the solution explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I finally find an answer as soon as I post the question. The ReSharper shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> will locate the file in the solution explorer, and from there <kbd>F2</kbd> can be used in the usual fashion to rename the file.